# Trying to understand data passing in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to understand what is being passed from the parent component to the child component properties in the following React.js example (I'm working through [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html) tic-tac-toe tutorial):

```
class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <button className="square" onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>
        {this.props.value}
    </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Then there is a board component that does this to render each square:

```
renderSquare(i) {
  return <Square value={this.state.squares[i]} onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)} />;
}

handleClick(i) {
  const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
  squares[i] = 'X';
  this.setState({squares: squares});
}
```

squares is an array saved in the state of the board.

The render function of the board is like this:

```
render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

handleClick updates the squares array that is in Board without seemingly touching Square. This seems a little wonky from my viewpoint of a traditional Java/C++ programmer where I'm looking for something like pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value. The only thing I can guess about what is happening here is that after handleClick is called, the Board's render function is called again and that is how the new square[i] data value is passed to the Square component. So at that point, Square is rendered with a new set of props but the same state it had before. Is that correct?

Even if I'm correct in my understanding, it's what I'm really trying to wrap my head around as a way of *thinking* about the code I'm going to write. I'm also curious about more details about the control flow of React.js: When should I expect render() for a component to be called again? And does render of a parent call render of all the children it has? I'm curious about if a parent is re-rendered, do all the old child components get destroyed and then a new set is constructed and rendered? If not, how does React.js know which  call goes with which Square object?

I'm interested in any advice about how to understand this or articles with good analogies/descriptions about this subject. Even just some jargon about how to describe what is going on here would help me in my own Googling. Thanks, all!

Full example [here](https://codepen.io/allisonf/pen/LbbjYx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question! You're asking the right things and I can tell that you're going to have a strong grasp of React within a short time frame. It seems like you could use some help to better understand the component lifecycle and the beauty of one-way data binding. I'll list some resources that you might find help and I'll try my best to answer your specific questions below.

**This is a good article on component lifecycles:**

http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

Another great resource/tool is Redux. Not only is it a great tool for debugging but it also helps you learn because it makes it much easier to visualize what is going on behind the scenes.

**Redux:** https://github.com/reactjs/redux

**Questions & Answers:**

1) ... curious about more details about the control flow of React.js

When an instance of a component is being created and inserted into the DOM, the following methods are called in this order:

- constructor()
- componentWillMount()
- render()
- compnentDidMount()

These methods are called when a component is being re-rendered:

- componentWillReceiveProps()
- shouldComponentUpdate()
- render()
- componentDidUpdate()

2) When should I expect render() for a component to be called again?

It's hard to give you a definitive statement as there are a lot of factors that come into play here. Typically, render() gets invoked when you need to load data from a remote endpoint, changes in the values of Props (which could trigger a state change), and changes in state. In other words, when something changes or updates and it requires DOM manipulation, we will likely re-render.

3) Does render of a parent call render of all the children it has?

4) If parent is re-rendered, do all the old child components get destroyed?

3 & 4 here are pretty similar question. When you use setState it is not only the current component that will do a render, but also all nested components. But if a nested component does a setState it will not affect parent components. From my understanding, child components will not get destroyed unless you specify compoentWillUnmount() or by performing clean up operations.

Answer (score 0):

React re-renders a component and its children whenever it is dirty, i.e. its props or state changed.

In your case, by calling `setState()`, you change the state of your board component and for this reason trigger a rendering of it and all its children.

Note that this does not necessarily mean that all DOM elements are deleted and replaced, as React may reuse them where possible for performance reasons. This process however is abstracted away by the React library for you.